# Where are Tomcat 9 sessions stored in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: tomcat

The manual below says:

[Apache Tomcat 9 Configuration Reference - The Manager Component](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/manager.html#Introduction)

> Introduction
>
> A Manager element MAY be nested inside a Context component. If it is
> not included, a default Manager configuration will be created
> automatically

My Context has no nested Manager element:

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
</Context>
```

So, the default is to be used:

[The Manager Component - Standard Manager Implementation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/manager.html#Standard_Implementation)

> `pathname`: Absolute or relative (to the work directory for this
> Context) pathname of the file in which session state will be preserved
> across application restarts, if possible. The default is
> "**SESSIONS.ser**".

The question is, where can I find this `SESSIONS.ser` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't configure a session manager explicitly, one is provided for you. If the attribute `pathname` is a relative location, it is resolved against the application's working directory, which is by default:

```
$CATALINA_BASE/work/[enginename]/[hostname]/[appname]
```

(usually `$CATALINA_BASE/work/Catalina/localhost/[appname]`).

Following symbolic links on Ubuntu it is situated in:

```
/var/cache/tomcat9/[enginename]/[hostname]/[appname]
```

You can change the location of the working directory setting the `workDir` parameter of `<Host>` (c.f. [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation)).

Comment: I couldn't find any sessions there. Is it possible they are only in memory?

Comment: While the application is running they are kept in memory. To write them to disk stop the application (e.g. stop the server).